# Shoot a picture with flashlight?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

- How can I shoot a picture with flashlight under Android ?

*/ Flex 4.6 and Flex 4.9 /*

```
            camera      = Camera.getCamera( cameraIndex );  

            cameraWidth  = 1280;//camera.width; 
            cameraHeight = 720;//camera.height;

            videoHolder = new UIComponent();
            video       = new Video( cameraWidth, cameraHeight );

            trace( cameraWidth, cameraHeight );

            camera.setMode( cameraWidth, cameraHeight, 24 );

            video.attachCamera( camera );
            videoHolder.addChild( video );
            cameraGroup.addElement( videoHolder );
```

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: sure. it is Flex/Actionscript 3 dev question.

Comment: There is no documentation on the topic. I have added a piece of the code used for shooting pictures.

Comment: I don't understand what "with flashlight" means.  Is that a feature of Android?

Comment: So far, you've added a camera to your stage (which should probably work), but you don't have any code demonstrating your actual issue.  If by "shoot a picture with a flashlight" you mean "use the camera light values to affect a loaded Bitmap's color values to give the impression of being lit by the light sampled from the camera"... then the possible approaches are high.  The simplest, is probably to scale the video input to your target Bitmap and add the values from both to createa a new image.  This wouldn't look great.  Conversely, if you mean, "Light a camera using a virtual flashlight"...

Comment: I mean using the hardware persisting flash. And since there is no documentation, neither i was able to find any code sample on the topic, i haven't tried anything so far, and that's why i am asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it in pure ActionScript, however you should be able to do it through a Native Extension (named ANE), as described here : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html

I didn't found any existing ANE that doing what you need, so you will have to do it yourself.